# Why doesn't my form with javascript work?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form (im using bootstrap) with 3 number inputs and with the numbers im doing math, this is my code

```js
function abc() {
      var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
      var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
      var c = document.getElementById("c").value;

      var d = Math.pow((b), 2) - (4 * a * c);
              
      var x1 = (-b-(Math.sqrt(d))) / (2 * a);

      var x2 = (-b+(Math.sqrt(d))) / (2 * a);

      document.write(d);
    }
```

```html
<div class="row"><!-- Row -->
        <div class="col-md-4"><!-- Rij links -->
          <form onsubmit="abc()" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="a">Vul hier a in:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="a" placeholder="Ax2 + bx + c" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="b">Vul hier b in:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="b" placeholder="ax2 + Bx + c" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="c">Vul hier c in:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="c" placeholder="ax2 + bx + C" >
            </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Ga!</button>
          </form>
        </div><!-- Einde Rij links -->
        <div class="col-md-4"><!-- Rij rechts -->
          <p>Je antwoord komt hieronder:</p>
          <p id="antwoord"></p>
        </div><!-- Einde Rij rechts -->
        <div class="col-md-4">

        </div>
      </div><!-- Einde Row -->
```

my javascript is right before the closing body tag.

at first the code worked but than suddenly it stopped working. it does nothing

Comment: Stopped working means? it is diaplaying an answer, when the button is clicked..

Comment: The form submits because there's nothing preventing it from submitting, thus reloading the page.

Comment: Run code snippet seems to work for me, I have no idea what sort of math it is doing though!

Comment: Seems its working in the code snippet ??

Comment: @craigie2204 It seems to me like its the quadratic formula, used for calculating intersections with the x axis of a second power polynomal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onsubmit function is not preventing the page from sending the request back to the server. Best practice is to return false at the end of the abc function:

```
 function abc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var d = Math.pow((b), 2) - (4 * a * c);
  var x1 = (-b-(Math.sqrt(d))) / (2 * a);
  var x2 = (-b+(Math.sqrt(d))) / (2 * a);
  document.write(d);

  return false;
}
```

You should also update the onsubmit as follows:

```
 <form onsubmit="return abc()" role="form">
```

Hope that helps!